# Swift - Replacing Label text with Value from API

Tags: api, swift, interpolation

Im trying to create a button, that when pressed, changes the label text to the value returned from the API.

I have made a simple php page to query my database and return a 'count'.

Within my IBAction, I can set the label text to an ordinary string like "test" and it works fine, but if i try to use interpolation it doesn't seem to work..

For debugging purposes i added the line

```
println( "TypeName0 = \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(kik))")
```

where kik is my variable that is assigned the value from the API, when running this i get

```
TypeName0 = Swift.String
```

Which is what i expect, as i want to replace the labelText.text = kik

Can anyone explain why i can easily replace the labelText with an ordinary string and not the value that is returned from the API?

my full code is below.

```
 @IBAction func getSavingsCardCount(sender: AnyObject) {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://testurlforstackoverflow.php")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){(data, response, error)  in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () in
            let kik = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
            println( "TypeName0 = \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(kik))")
                // self.scCountLabel.text = "TEST WORKS!"   this will work but the following line will not
                self.scCountLabel.text = "\(kik)"
                println(kik)
             })

        }
    task.resume()
     }
```

[image]

Comment: Whats ouputs `println(kik)`?

Comment: I get this back in the console. `220098` but it seems strange, because there is an extra(blank) line above that print in the console. so the full console response by clicking that button would be `TypeName0 = Swift.String

 220098
`

Comment: And what should be the value returned by the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like i was having an issue with the value that was being returned, as it had a line break before it, and some leading white space (2 characters)  so when testing with `println(newString.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))`
 I was getting 8, now after implementing

```
var newString = kik.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

i get 6, which is the correct length of the string..

for anyone else having this issue, pay attention to your console and note any line breaks or strange spacing issues in your println() statements, for me  using the following code to remove white spaces worked.

```
  var newString = kik.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```